# Translating baptism record from Norway?

Tags: baptism-records, translation, norway

Following is a transcribed record for my 2nd Great-Grandmother taken from the Digital Archives of Norway. I believe that I have managed to translate most of the record accurately, but am a little unsure about the note (morknader). The original reads, "Anmeldt personlig af Barnets Fader Anders Taraldsen Korslund. Far leierm 1 Mor leierm 1." I believe roughly translates to "Reviewed personally by child's father Anders Taraldsen of Korslund. Father leierm 1 Mother leierm 1." I am hoping that someone can confirm my translation of the record (located at the bottom of the image).

[image: Baptism Record for Johanne Frederikke Andersd.]

Comment: Would you be able to include the translated (and original) words as text rather than just a picture so that it can be available to future searches, please?

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm your understanding of the "Merknader" (remarks), although I am not familiar with norwegian church records. The word "leierm" is apparently short for "leiermål" which also has a corresponding term "lägersmål" in swedish. In the more familiar finnish books I have often seen similar markings including the counts like "1st time adultery".

One note about your translation is, that "Anmeldt personlig af ..." would translate to "Reported in person by ...

Comment: Thank you. You have been very helpful. I have been struggling with this for some time, particularly the word "leierm" since I couldn't find it anywhere and assumed it was probably an abbreviation.